# Links to download\delete from a directory

Tags: php

I have upload and download scripts. Here they are:

Upload

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Result </title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    echo '<pre>';


    if (!empty($_FILES) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File was succesfully uploaded to ".$uploaddir;
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong. Attach you file, please. \n";
    }


    //
    //if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] > 500000) {
    //    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.\n";
    //}

    $filelist = scandir($uploaddir, 1);

?>
    <p> Download your files: </p>

    <table>
        <?php foreach($filelist as $file): ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $file; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

<?php
//debug
//   print_r ($filelist);
//   print_r($_FILES);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Download

```
<?php 

// block any attempt to the filesystem
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
} else {
    $filename = NULL;
}


$error = 'Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable for ya.';

if (!$filename) {
// if  $filename is NULL or false display the message
    echo $error;
} else {
    $path = '/var/www/uploads/'.$filename;
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
// display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
// stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo $error;
        }
    } else {
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Now I can see just the list of the files I uploaded.

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpbr5.png)

I want to make them ***links*** so I can download and delete (using GET and unlink) each file from the directory. I assume I have to use foreach but I still can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something seems off with your code. The first snippet, which you marked as "Upload", contains no form for uploading files, but it does contain a list of files introduced by `Download your files:` and generated by a `foreach` loop. The second snippet, marked as "Download" does seem to be related to downloading, but it isn't obvious how it interacts with the user. Both snippets are unclear. Perhaps you can simplify your code and show more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make them links:

```
<?php foreach($filelist as $file): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="download.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite easy :)